# Question on weakly stationary

Tags: time-series, self-study, econometrics, covariance, stationarity

Let $Y_t$ is time trend process i.e., $Y_t=b_t+e_t$ for $e_t$follows NID(0,$\sigma^2$)

Is this process covariance (weakly) stationary?

Comment: To my knowledge, no. The $b_t$ with a $t$ subscript represents the presence of a trend/the mean trending with time. They often call this (confusingly), a trend-stationary process (stationarised by removing the trend).

Comment: @EB3112 covariance is constant

Comment: @Aksakal. Weak stationarity considers the first two moments, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @aksakal you mean this process is weakly stationary?

Comment: @EB3112 how can I Show what you said in formal way?

Comment: @1190. That's very much a homework question from an introductory time series class. However, I would say, I would look at a book by Brooks 'Introductory Econometrics for Finance'; the answer is in there.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation @EB3112

Comment: Do we have any information about $b_t$?